# Unity 3D low FPS and bad performance when switching mobile

Tags: android, performance, mobile, unity-game-engine

Seven months ago I began to develop a 3D game in Unity for Android.

I tried to get 60 fps, and the game worked perfectly.
I tested the game with my Samsung Note 3 Neo and everything worked fine having 60 fps.

But one week ago I have changed my mobile phone to a Huawei Ascend Mate 7.
The new mobile is more performant than the other and all games I tried are faster and smoother. However, not my game.

Using my new Huawei phone my game is executed with 20 fps, only and I do not have any clue for that.
Furthermore shadows look very bad. I changed all the quality setting, but did not get and improvements by doing this.

Could someone give me some hints please about how to improve my game's performance in the way I intend to?

Comment: Try finding the bottleneck with the Unity Profiler.

Comment: Can you check poly counts and drawcalls ? Then we can decide better.

Comment: I have 160k Tris and Verts in the higher point. 166 Draw Calls. And in the Profiler I don't see nothing weird, camera render spends 60% of CPU with 1.4 ms. It's okey, in my old mobile works very well but I now is not working. Do you think it could be something that makes conflict with Huawei processor?

Answer (score 2):

According to this review: http://www.anandtech.com/show/8655/the-huawei-ascend-mate-7-review/4 Huawei has poorer GPU performance than Samsung.

Also you have unacceptable amount of drawcalls: you need to get it down to vicinity of 30 if you wish to make your game playable on low end devices.